# Opinion that nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard are the same

Tags: tefilla, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

I remember hearing an opinion somewhere that nusach Ashkenaz and nusach Sefard (but not real nusach Sfaradi/Edot Hamizrach!) are both basically the same nusach, since they are structurally very similar. I think this would mean that a chazan in an Ashkenazic kehillah could use either nusach without worrying about lo tisgodedu. Is this a real opinion, and if so, who brought it down?

Comment: Look at shmoneh esri ,they are so different.

Comment: The point is that nusach Sefard is sort of just nusach Ashkenaz with Sefardisms thrown in, rather than being a davar bifnei atzmo.

Comment: @sam not to mention _p'suke d'zimra_, especially on _Shabas_.

Comment: See Igros Moshe Ohr Hachaim 2:24

Comment: What's the difference if it's the same with extra or different?

Comment: @sam - It depends on who prints the Nusach Sefard siddur...ArtScroll's Nusach Sefard siddurim have an identical Shemoneh Esrei.

Comment: @Ezrahoerster, that is a false statement I have davemed from both numerous times ,the discrepancies are very discernable and if one isn't used to their nusach they would be very confused,so don't know what siddur yi UT talking abiut

Comment: Hmmm...maybe I should look back into both my ArtScroll siddurim and see for sure.

Answer (score 1):

There are many differences between Nusach Ashkenaz, the traditional German and Lithuanian nusach, and Nusach Sefard, the Chassidishe nusach. One way they are different is in the way the prayers are ordered. I've included the order of Pesukei D'zimrah for weekdays for both nusachim:

**נוסח אשכנז פסוקי דזמרה לחול**

תהילים ל,
קדיש יתום,
הריני מזמן...בשם כל ישראל,
ברוך שאמר,
הודו,
תהילים ק,
יהי כבוד,
אשרי,
תהילים קמו,
תהילים קמז,
תהילים קמח,
תהילים קמט,
תהילים קנ,
ברוך ה' לעולם אמן ואמן...אמן ואמן,
ויברך,
וכרות, 
ויושע,
אז-ישיר-משה,
ישתבח,
חצי קדיש

**נוסח ספרד פסוקי דזמרה לחול**

הודו,
תהילים ל,
ה' מלך...ושמו אחד,
הושיענו...קה, הללוקה,
תהילים סז,
הריני מזמן...בשם כל ישראל,
ברוך שאמר,
תהילים ק,
יהי כבוד,
אשרי,
תהילים קמו,
תהילים קמז,
תהילים קמח,
תהילים קמט,
תהילים קנ,
ברוך ה' לעולם אמן ואמן...אמן ואמן,
ויברך,
וכרות,
ויושע,
אז-ישיר-משה,
ישתבח,
חצי קדיש

Obviously, the order of the prayers differs between the two nusachim. But there's more than just order that makes them different. A few textual differences (there are many between the two, here are just some examples):

- Mourner's Kaddish is included after Psalm 30 in Nusach Ashkenaz, but in Nusach Sefard it is not there.
- Boruch She'omar differs slightly between them. Here's how Nusach Ashkenaz begins Boruch She'omar:

> ברוך שאמר והיה העולם, ברוך הוא. ברוך עשה בראשית, ברוך אומר ועשה, ברוך גוזר ומקים, ברוך מרחם על הארץ...

And here's how Nusach Sefard begins it:

> ברוך שאמר והיה העולם, ברוך הוא. ברוך אומר ועשה, ברוך גוזר ומקים, ברוך עשה בראשית, ברוך מרחם על הארץ...

There's clearly some differences here.

- Yishtabach differs majorly between the two. Here's how Nusach Ashkenaz renders it:

> ישתבח שמך לעד מלכנו, הקל המלך הגדול והקדוש, בשמים ובארץ. כי לך נאה, ה' אלקינו ואלקי אבותינו, שיר ושבחה, הלל וזמרה, עז וממשלה, נצח, גדלה וגבורה, תהילה ותפארת, קדשה ומלכות, ברכות והודאות מעתה ועד עולם. ברוך אתה ה', קל מלך גדול בתשבחות, קל ההודאות, אדון הנפלאות, הבוחר בשירי זמרה, מלך, קל, חי העולמים.

And here's how Nusach Sefard renders it:

> ישתבח שמך לעד מלכנו, הקל המלך הגדול והקדוש, בשמים ובארץ. כי לך נאה, ה' אלקינו ואלקי אבותינו, שיר ושבחה, הלל וזמרה, עז וממשלה, נצח גדלה וגבורה, תהילה ותפארת, קדשה ומלכות, ברכות והודאות לשמך הגדול והקדוש, ומעולם ועד עולם אתה קל. ברוך אתה ה', קל מלך גדול ומהלל בתשבחות, קל ההודאות, אדון הנפלאות, בורא כל הנשמות, רבון כל המעשים, הבוחר בשירי זמרה, מלך יחיד קל חי העולמים.

LOTS OF DIFFERENCE. And this is just in Pesukei D'zimrah for weekdays. Some other differences in the Shacharis for Shabbos include the inclusion of L'chai Olamim, even though most Nusach Sefard congregations don't recite it aloud, and more. One big difference is right here:

Nusach Ashkenaz

> שוכן עד מרום וקדוש שמו. וכתוב: רננו צדיקים בה', לישרים נאוה תהילה:
>   בפי ישרים תתהלל, ובדברי צדיקים תתברך, ובלשון חסידים תתרומם, ובקרב קדושים תתקדש.

Nusach Sefard

> שוכן עד מרום וקדוש שמו: וכתוב: רננו צדיקים בה', לישרים נאוה תהילה: בפי ישרים תתרומם, ובשפתי צדיקים תתברך, ובלשון חסידים תתקדש, ובקרב קדושים תתהלל.

Clearly different as well.

As for Shemoneh Esrei, some people have informed me that the ArtScroll Nusach Ashkenaz and Nusach Sefard differ in this regard. However, I've davened from both and haven't found any differences. If anyone would like to show me the differences IN AN ARTSCROLL SIDDUR (I'm sure the Shemoneh Esrei is different in other Nusach Sefard publications), I would really like to see them. To my knowledge, since ArtScroll-Mesorah is a primarily Litvish publishing company, their Shemoneh Esrei doesn't change between the nusachim.

Hope this helps. And a lot of the portions I've listed are recited by the chazzan, so a person who davens Nusach Sefard might have a hard time following in a shul that uses Nusach Ashkenaz or vice versa.

By the way, I've used סדור תפארת צבי for the Nusach Ashkenaz, and סדור תפארת יעקב for the Nusach Sefard. Both are printed by ArtScroll and are both all-Hebrew editions.)

Comment: Shma koleinu vs. Av harachaman shma koleinu.

Comment: _nakdishakh vna'aritzakh_ vs. _nikadesh es shimcha_ in most _kedushas_ and _keser yitnu lecha_ vs _na'aritzikha vnakdishikha_ in _musaf_. As well as differences in other lines of _kedusha_

Comment: berov oz uvshalom